Axon Event Handlers de-register/unsubscribe automatically
I have an event handler for the query mechanism and everything works as is in the tests with Axon Server disabled.
But after deploying the Spring application to make it register the event handlers, they are immediately de-registered.
Does anybody have leads what we should look into for this?
We are using Axon 4.10.0.
Sample logs:
org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessorcluster_name: xxx-xxxfile: TrackingEventProcessor.javakubernetes: { \[+\]}line: 758
logger: org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor
logtag: F
message: Processor 'orderinfo' awaiting termination...
method: awaitTerminationservice: xxx-order-service
severity: INFO
stream: stdout
thread: SpringApplicationShutdownHook
time: 2024-08-08T11:42:13.286525436Z
timestamp: 2024-08-08T11:42:13.286298724Z

----------

host = splunk-fluentd-0
source = fluentd
sourcetype = http:
event8/8/2411:42:14.575 AM  { \[-\]
class: org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessorcluster_name:
file: TrackingEventProcessor.javakubernetes: { \[+\]}line: 374logger: org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor
logtag: F
message: Released claim
method: releaseToken
service: xxx-order-service
severity: INFO
stream: stdout
thread: EventP

host = splunk-fluentd-0
source = fluentdsourcetype = http:
event8/8/2411:42:14.575 AM  { \[-\]
class: io.axoniq.axonserver.connector.command.impl.CommandChannelImplcluster_name:
file: CommandChannelImpl.javakubernetes: { \[+\]}
line: 288
logger: io.axoniq.axonserver.connector.command.impl.CommandChannelImpl
logtag: F
message: Deregistered handler for command 'com.xxx.xxx.order.control.manual.command.CreateManualOrderCommand' in context 'default'
method: unsubscribe
service: xxx-order-service
severity: INFO
stream: stdout
thread: SpringApplicationShutdownHook
time: 2024-08-08T11:42:13.909849444Z
timestamp: 2024-08-08T11:42:13.909430347Z}

I need help in what needs to be done to handle this or get this problem sorted.

It seems to me that your application is immediately shutting down on start-up.
This might be Axon Framework related, but with the given log lines it is not clear to me if that's the case.
The log's you have shared are lines you would expect upon an application shutdown.
So, if you could share more logs on the shutdown moment, that would be great.
For that, I would look at the Spring-specific logs, as it is likely an initiated shutdown right after a start-up.

Apologies for the delay i have been trying to get the spring logs from the cloud env but its not happening per transaction but only certain period and not sure how to get the logs. Currently have the tracing enabled for     io:
axoniq: DEBUG
org:
axonframework: DEBUG
springframework: DEBUG ---- Do you think i should add some more logging for providing the logs?

Also the log is not gettign attached here , even tried pasting the contents but still the same- But if you can help me letting me know more specificly which trace to be enabled then i would provide only that

It is pretty hard to tell you "this is the log line I am looking for" as there are tons of options which might cause this. I would hope that setting the log levels to DEBUG would at least show some WARN/ERROR message stating a reason why the application will shut down.
By the way, my gut tells me it is Spring Boot causing the shutdown, not Axon Framework.
